# Graphql Codegen specifying optional fields

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen, urql

Say I have the following fragment:

```
fragment ConversationSnippet on Conversation {
    uuid
    unreadMessages
    profileThatHasUnreadMessages
    updatedAt
    createdAt
    profiles{
        ...ConversationProfileSnippet
    }
    messages{
        ...MessageSnippet
    }
    ongoingCall
    pendingCall
    pendingCallProfile {
        ...ConversationProfileSnippet
    }
}
```

The `pendingCallProfile` could be null null. Is there a way for me to specify that in the fragment? I'm facing an issue where if the `pendingCallProfile` is null the entire query fails to return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a simple solution, all I had to do was specify that the field was nullable on the Conversation entity server side.

```
  @Field(() => Profile, { nullable: true })
  @OneToOne(() => Profile, {
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  pendingCallProfile: Profile
```